# Why is my binary smaller when using -fno-aggressive-loop-optimizations?

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization

Lately I got a warning about possible undefined behaviour and read that it has to do with a new aggressive loop optimization and this could be turned off using -fno-aggressive-loop-optimizations (using gcc). I tried this and found out that the binary is smaller with this option active. Not much, just 5 hex lines in a 180k hexfile.
Now my question is how can an active optimization make a binary larger or switching off this optimization make it smaller? Would you recommend to have the aggressive optimization active or not?
(I read GCC 4.8 release notes)
Thank you

Comment: Nearly any kind of optimization can make the binary either larger or smaller.  [Loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling) is a notable example.  GCC has a separate option `-funroll-loops` for that, but it could be that it interacts with `-faggressive-loop-optimizations` in some way.

Comment: @NateEldredge: GCC doesn't enable `-funroll-loops` even at `-O3`, only with profile-guided optimization.   (Not for many years, I think even the old GCC4.8 that Martin was reading release notes for wouldn't have enabled it that way.)  But fully unrolling small loops is a separate thing; GCC calls that "loop peeling".  It can sometimes cost a bit of code size, but usually good for speed.

Comment: Your choices for optimization options depend on the target CPU / environment.  e.g. `-Os` makes a lot of sense if small code might let you use a smaller ROM chip in an embedded device, or if a normal `-O3` build ends up bloating your executable so much that you're getting lots of I-cache misses.  But if your code has a few loops where it spends most of its time, having GCC do everything it can for those loops is a good thing.  Test and benchmark your code with realistic data on the actual CPUs you care about.